# Unique key do not repeat themselves

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with these columns:

```
Id -
Part number A - 
Part number B -
```

I need you to not allow me the following

```
Id | PartNumberA | PartNumberB  
---+-------------+------------
 1 | TEST        | TEST            -> not allowed, because PartNumberA is equal to PartNumberB
 2 | TEST        | BLAH            -> not allowed
 3 | FFF         | BLAH            -> not allowed
```

I try to create a unique key:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Producto_PartNumberA_PartNumberB] 
ON [dbo].[Producto] ([PartNumberA] ASC, [PartNumberB] ASC)
```

But if I try to insert the value "TEST" in both columns, it allows it and I don't want that.

I need the columns not to repeat themselves, and between each other

Comment: Why `TEST` & `BLAH` is also not allowed?

Comment: I need them not to repeat themselves
For ex
Part Number A only allow one TEST.
So 
2|TEST|BLAH not allow because TEST already exist in row 1

Comment: The above comment is asking whether you are trying to enforce uniqueness within each _column_ or across both columns?  That being said, are you stuck with the current table design, or can it be changed?

Comment: can be changed without problem

Comment: I need part numberA not to repeat in PartNumberA.
I also need part number B to not repeat in PartNumberB.
and that PartNumberA and PartNumberB do not repeat themselves, that is, partNumberA cannot be TEST and partNumberB be TEST as well.

Comment: Have you tried creating a UNIQUE KEY individually on each column and then create a trigger to check across columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really have a unique constraint that spans both columns.  However, you can come pretty close with the following contraints:

- `PartNumberA` is unique
- `PartNumberB` is unique
- `PartNumberA < PartNumberB`

That would be:

```
create unique index unq_producto_partnumberA on producto(partnumberA);

create unique index unq_producto_partnumberB on producto(partnumberB);

alter table producto add constraint chk_producto_AB check (partnumberA < partnumberB);
```

This might not meet exactly your needs -- but if you can insist on an ordering for the columns, then it would seem to do what you want.

Comment: I tried both ways and they both work the same.
Name Part number A Part number B
Name 1  TEST TEST2 
Name 2  TEST2 test

If I understand you correctly, shouldn't your script allow them to intersect?
perform the test and this data allows us to enter the database

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want `UNIQUE` & `CHECK` constraints

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    ID int,
    PartNumberA varchar(255) UNIQUE,
    PartNumberB varchar(255) UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT chk_test CHECK (PartNumberA<>PartNumberB)
);
```

Comment: if you feel this answer also helped you, you can upvote(_by clicking up arrow just above tick mark_)